# React and Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to use Leaflet in my React App. I'm running into an issue. Leaflet.js requires the div component to pre-exist when initiating the map. React doesn't "create" the div until it renders the component, so leaflet is throwing an error. Both getDOMNode() and findDOMNode() return "not a function" for whatever reason.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import L from 'leaflet';
```

...a little later

```
export default class Mapbox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

    return (

      <div id="map">
    <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>
    );
```

This returns an error that "Map Container not Found".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize map inside [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)

```
class Mapbox extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.map();
  }

  map() {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="map">xx</div>  
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44686/)

Comment: Oh my days it WORKS, the only thing I changed was adding a height to the `div` to get it to show up

    `return <div id="map" style={{height: '200px'}}>xx</div>`

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are great if you're using class components. If you have to use it with functional components (using **Hooks**) than you might need to code `useRef`.

```
function Map({}) {
  // define the ref here
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect( () => {
// set the initialized map to the ref
    mapRef.current = L.map('map').setView([51.505, 3], 13);
    
    }, []);

// pass it in the required div node
  return (
    <div ref={mapRef} id="map" className="p-2">
    </div>
  );

}
```

In this way the map will be initialized after the DOM node is rendered.

Reference: [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Answer (score 1):

Since react `16.3` there is a new method for creating references easily.

> note:the references can be stored in constructor as the refernces can be created prior to the jsx div is created.

```
class Map extends React.Component {


  componentDidMount() {
   this.map = React.createRef();
   var map = L.map(this.map).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.map}></div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "refs". Refs is used to return a reference to the element. 
docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
class Map extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const node = this.node;
    var map = var map = L.map(node).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={(node) => { this.node = node }}></div>
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `React.createRef()` is the way to go. The old callback refs isn’t recommended.